# Select All checkboxes in a List with Jquery

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, toggle

Here is an sample/example of HTML/jQuery I'm working with.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#check_all_uw").change(function() {
    var checkboxes_uw = $(this).closest(".China-uw-class").find(":checkbox");
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      checkboxes_uw.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      checkboxes_uw.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="China-uw" class="tabcontent-uw" style="display: block;">
  <h3 id="china-h3" class="uw-h3" style="font-weight:lighter;">China</h3>
  <div id="China-ul" class="China-uw-class">
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" class="uw-checkbox">Select All</label></div>
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" class="uw-checkbox">Zhang Yi</label></div>
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" class="uw-checkbox">Ken Yan</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `#check_all_uw` element in your HTML

Comment: Correct the id for select all checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed code is `is()`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#check_all_uw").change(function() {
    $(".uw-checkbox:checkbox")
      .not(this)
      .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="China-uw" class="tabcontent-uw" style="display: block;">
  <h3 id="china-h3" class="uw-h3" style="font-weight:lighter;">China</h3>
  <div id="China-ul" class="China-uw-class">
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" id="check_all_uw" class="uw-checkbox">Select All</label></div>
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" class="uw-checkbox">Zhang Yi</label></div>
    <div><label><input type="checkbox" class="uw-checkbox">Ken Yan</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was creating lists and then divs for multiple countries using a for loop, and lost track of what I was doing. Much appreciated.